# Custom Identifier generation in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Currently working on a multi-tenant application, have an issue in generating identifier in a stored procedure.

I have a this table which has a meta information about tenant.

**Tenant**

```
TenantId
Name
IDPrefix,   -->Like SFT
IDStart     --> 000001
```

**Client**

```
TenantID
ClientIdentfier --> Like SFT000001
```

In a stored procedure I want to generate the next `ClientIdentifier` like `SFT000002`.

How can I do it based on last `ClientIdentifier` value + 1 ?

I know only taking last value with this below code.

```
select max(ClientID) + 1 from Client will give 1,2,etc
```

But I think I can't do like

```
 DECLARE @CIdentier Varchar(50);

 select @CIdentier = select max(ClientIdentifier) + 1 from Client 
                                            to produce 'SFT000002
```

How can I do like this in a stored procedure?

**Edit:**

Tried mark_s answer and it worked like a charm!!!

Comment: been asked before on SO....

Comment: @MitchWheat Can i get that SO link? i searched and failed.

Comment: A `SELECT MAX(ClientID) + 1` approach is **never safe** under load - you will get duplicates.

Comment: Use IDENTITY(1,1) and if you need to generate an ID like SFTxxxxxx, you can generate it from the ID,and you can keep the duplicates away

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for the tip. But is there a nice way to do this under a load? The application will be used by many tenants, so if you add some more point to do, it will be helpful

Comment: @user1909604: added a response with an approach that is known to work - even under heavy load

Comment: The `INSERTED` pseudo table **only exists** within a trigger or within an `OUTPUT` clause .... you cannot do this as you have it. You need to leave the "fetch next ClientID" as a **separate stored procedure** - you cannot just include this in the middle of your long `AddClient` procedure..

Comment: @marc_s I got you. Let me try those and update my question accordingly. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @user1909604: see the UPDATE to my response - shows how to use this stored procedure to get the next client ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach will be safe under load, e.g. it's not going to return any duplicates, even if lots of client requests come in at the same time (this is "borrowed" from an answer by @remusrusanu to another question on SO).

Basically, you need a sequence table with columns `TenantID`, `TenantPrefix` and `CurrentValue` and then you can use a stored procedure like this to safely fetch new values:

```
-- add a IDValue column to your Tenant table
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tenant
ADD IDValue INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)

-- create this procedure to fetch the next value for any given tenant
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetNextTenantID
   @tenantID INT,    
   @NextID VARCHAR(15) OUTPUT
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @Out TABLE (NextVal INT, Prefix CHAR(3))

   UPDATE dbo.Tenant
   SET IDValue = IDValue + 1
   OUTPUT INSERTED.IDValue, INSERTED.IDPrefix INTO @Out(NextVal, prefix)

   SELECT TOP 1 @nextID = Prefix + CAST(NextVal AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM @Out
GO
```

The main point here is: you have to do the incrementing the `IDValue` and the returning of it inside a **single** `UPDATE` statement. Only with this approach can you be safe under load - all the approaches that have a `SELECT` first, increment, and then `UPDATE` are **not** safe and can return duplicates.

**Update:** you **cannot** just include this snippet of code into a larger procedure of yours! Leave this procedure **as is** and just call it from your stored procedure - something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddClient]  
(
   @TenantId INT,
   @FirstName NVARCHAR(100),
   @LastName NVARCHAR(100),
   @ContactPerson NVARCHAR(100)
)
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON   

     IF @TenantId IS NULL 
        RAISERROR('The value for @TenantID should not be null', 15, 1) -- with log

     DECLARE @new_person_id INT
     DECLARE @new_patient_id INT
     DECLARE @ClientIdentifier NVARCHAR(50)

     -- call the stored procedure to get the next ClientIdentifier here
     EXEC dbo.GetNextTenantID @TenantID, @ClientIdentifier OUTPUT

     -- then go on and do your other lines of code from here on out .....
     ......
END
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I follow this way!

Comment: Can i make this GetNextTenantID as function and use it in stored procedure?

Comment: @user1909604: no you cannot - functions cannot modify the database

Comment: @user1909604: if you try to convert this to a function, you'll get an error something like this: `Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure ......, Line 7 / Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'UPDATE' within a function.`

Comment: I tried the same inside the procedure itself and got some new error!. Updated that with my question. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: After adding WHERE clause i am getting Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'. How do we include? Updated question

Answer (score 1):

if you have fixed prefix length and right digit length:

### [Here is SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1bd5/7)

```
with T as 
(select 
    (isnull(max(ClientIdentfier),'SFT000000')) maxNum
from client
)

select substring(maxNum,1,3)+
       RIGHT('000000'+
             cast(cast(right(maxNum,6) as bigint)+1 as varchar(100)),
             6)
   from T
```

If you need to get next number for defined TenantID for example TenantID=2 then use following query:

```
with T as 
(select 
    (isnull(max(ClientIdentfier),
            select top 1 IDPrefix+IDStart 
                from Tenant 
             where TenantID=2)) maxNum
from client 
     where TenantID=2
)

select substring(maxNum,1,3)+
       RIGHT('000000'+
             cast(cast(right(maxNum,6) as bigint)+1 as varchar(100)),
             6)
   from T
```

Comment: It looks great. However each tenant might have their own identifier and start number. Example tenant 2 might have 'TET' and Start Number '20569'. Is there a way to read those and generate next number?

Comment: I've added a query to get next number for defined Tenantid